# Why can't I like a comment using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to implement a solution for me and, by this time, I'm able to post to my feed, like the posts, comment them, but I'm not able to like comments (none of them), I get the message: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) the parameter url is required.
Can anyone help??

Answer (score 5):

The other answers might have been true in the past, but they are no longer true. Comments also have an ID, and when you post to `/ID/likes`, the comment is liked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the  Graph API permits liking of individual comments? The documentation shows examples of how to like a post and how to comment on a post, but there's no indication I can see that says you can like a comment this way.

Comment: This should really be a comment should it not?

Comment: No? The answer is, I believe, "you can't do that".

Comment: this is no longer true, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Because the Facebook API does not support liking a comment using the Graph API or any API. The only way a comment can be liked is by using the Facebook website. Facebook has deliberately restricted the ability of a developer from "liking" anything using any of their APIs. Official like buttons are the only supported way to like anything.

Comment: Not entirely true. From the API: "You can comment on **or like a post** by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments and https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes, respectively." You can't programmatically like pages or comments, though, just wall posts.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. You can like posts through the API, but that is it. You can't like comments or external content through the API. This is deliberately restricted to control people forcing a user to like content. Additionally, you have to be very careful how use use the post like. If you aren't prompting the use to like the post you are going to get shut down due to a policy violation.

Comment: this is no longer true, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed now that you can't like comments in applications like HootSuite and Tweetdeck, as I'm doing a similar software, I have no reasons to worry about it.
Thanks for the answers!!!

Comment: this is no longer true, see my answer